# Select Into Variable and use it into IF (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, insert-into, select-into

I got procedure where I want to insert value to variable from Col1:

```
Procedure insertX
IS
 var1 varchar2(100) := '';
 check_s1 : = 'select Col1 into '||var1||' from table1';    
begin
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE check_s1;

  if var1 is null then
   ...
   else
   ...
  end if;    
end;
```

But when I execute it something goes wrong.

As I see select into had error.

How to insert the value to my Var1 and then use it in IF condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong syntax. Should be

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    var1 varchar2(100);
  3    check_s1 varchar2(100) := 'select dummy from dual';
  4  begin
  5    execute immediate check_s1 into var1;
  6
  7    if var1 is null then
  8       dbms_output.put_line('var1 is null');
  9    else
 10       dbms_output.put_line('var1 = ' || var1);
 11    end if;
 12  end;
 13  /
var1 = X

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```